# Faced the error when wanted to create pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to create pagination in index page and as I read in Laravel documentation it is possible to use paginate method with orderBy method when I do that I faced error:"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.". The code I am using:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::find($user_id);
        $personal=$user->personalAccounting->orderBy('asc')->paginate(2);
        $balance=$user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

    }  


 @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    <h1>Домашняя Бухгалтерия</h1>
    <br>
    @if($balance==0)
    <h2 class="text-center">Ваш Баланс: <span class="badge badge-primary">0.00</span></h2>
    @elseif($balance<0)
    <h3 class="text-center">Ваш Баланс: <span class="badge badge-danger">{{$balance}}</span></h3>
    @else
    <h3 class="text-center">Ваш Баланс: <span class="badge badge-success">+{{$balance}}</span></h3>
    @endif
    <br>
    <a href="/personal/create" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</a>
    <br>
    @if(count($personal)>0)
    @foreach($personal as $pers)
    <br>
        <div class="card">
            <h2><a href="/personal/{{$pers->id}}" >{{$pers->TypeOfAccounting}}</a></h2>
        <h5 class="">Наименование:<span class="badge">{{$pers->Name}}</span></h5>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{$personal->links()}}
    @else
    <p>Не найдено записей</p>


    @endif

    @stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = auth()->user(); // It's already the user model

        $personal = $user->personalAccounting()->orderBy('YOUR_COLUMN')->paginate(2);
        $balance = $user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

    }
```

Notice `personalAccounting()` instead of `personalAccounting` The reason is, when you call the attribute **without** `()`, Laravel will load all the data from your DB in a collection. Every modification you do after, will be done with PHP.
When you request with the method **using** `()`, you're modifying the QueryBuilder which mean the orderBy and the pagination will be executed by MySQL which will also increase the performance and reduce the memory usage.

Comment: hey dude thanks for your cool solution and with explanation.:)

Answer (score 0):

Give a column name before **asc**

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::find($user_id);
        $personal=$user->personalAccounting->orderBy('**your_column_name**','asc')->paginate(2);
        $balance=$user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

}
```

Comment: hi Minar, I have put column name but received exactly the same error:"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist."

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya, hi Mayuri, yeah tried it but got Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$personalAccounting"

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya, the code I am using 
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::where('id', $user_id);
        $personal=$user->personalAccounting->orderBy('id','asc')->paginate(2);
        $balance=$user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya, I have updated my question, please check it out, and sorry I am from Russia thus the app is inn Russian:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use latest().

public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::find($user_id);
        $personal=$user->personalAccounting->latest('***Add column name***')->paginate(2);
        $balance=$user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

    }
```